# The resource could not be loaded is ios9

Tags: ios9

while m calling my api got this error in ios9  but it is working fine in ios8
The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection ios9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add one flag in plist. See more at https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/3544

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it with adding some key in info.plist.
The steps I followed are:

1. Opened my Projects `info.plist` file
2. Added a Key called `NSAppTransportSecurity` as a `Dictionary`.
3. Added a Subkey called `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` as `Boolean` and set its value to `YES` as like following image.

[image]

Clean the Project and Now Everything is Running fine as like before.

Ref Link:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32631185/2905967
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32609970